# ABP .net core ,Vue template request signarl erver error

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I use Abp vue tempalte,install signarl,server is ok but vue  request signarl show error is http://localhost:8082/signalr-myChatHub/negotiate?e
  First, my server address is http://localhost:21029/signalr-myChatHub,request result is "Connection ID required" so my server is ok .
 now vue is error, vue template request return result is 
"

```
Cannot POST /signalr-myChatHub/negotiate
```

"
  Second, My Class is signalr-myChatHub,but vue request add "negotiate" in last,
"negotiate" is not I Add,Why auto add negotiate  in last

Who can help me ?

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not initial Framewoker, Initial Frmawork can solution this program

`app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.`